# How to train a L2-SVM classifier on top of a flattened vector of representations as per DCGAN paper

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pytorch

In the original [DCGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf), the GAN is partly evaluated by being used as a feature extractor to classify CIFAR-10, after having been trained on Imagenet.

From the paper:

> To evaluate the quality of the representations learned by DCGANs for supervised tasks,
>   we train on Imagenet-1k and then use the discriminator’s convolutional features from all layers,
>   maxpooling each layers representation to produce a 4 × 4 spatial grid. These features are then
>   flattened and concatenated to form a 28672 dimensional vector and a regularized linear L2-SVM
>   classifier is trained on top of them.

I have tried to replicate this using PyTorch to train the [official PyTorch DCGAN](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/dcgan/main.py) and then use scikit-learn to classify using their [linear SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC), but find the wording of the paper confusing and am not sure where to go from here. I've been able to maxpool each layer and then concatenate them, but am stumped on how to proceed with the classification of CIFAR-10.

In e.g. sklearn, you use `model.fit(x,y)` to fit the model according to the given training data, and then `model.predict([X])` to predict the class labels for the samples in `X`. In `model.fit(x,y)`, `x` is the (2D) features (e.g. images) and `y` is the labels. But it feels like they’re saying in the above quote make this `28672` dimensional vector the `x`. But that’s a 1D vector, and they use it to classify CIFAR-10, which has 50k images, and 50000 > 28672. Am I missing something obvious?

Do I use e.g. `model.fit` with `x` being the CIFAR-10 images (using e.g. `torchvision.datasets.cifar10`) (although how to make 50k `Tensors` of RGB images a 2D array is another story) and `y` being their labels, and then somehow predict using the 28672 dimensional vector?

Apologies if this is super obvious; unfortunately that’s all they say about it in the paper, and no one seems to have reproduced it (at least on GitHub etc.). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`DCGAN` would give you a 28672 dimenstional vector for each image. Hence the shape of the output of DCGAN woud be `(50000,28672)` for a complete `CIFAR10` dataset.

you have to take this as input for your sklearn SVM `x`, which as you mentioned takes a 2D data.

Comment: Thanks @AI_Learning ! Any idea how to make `x_test` (i.e. the 10k test images) 2D?
I tried to reshape the 32x32 RGB images using `.reshape(-1,3)` on the `np` array, but then I'm left with the result having the shape `(10000,1024,3)`